# css reset under a particular div

Tags: css

I know there are many questions similar but any of them didn't help. in a particular div I need to clear all css format from up level of this div.

for example "h2" has a style for all web site is pink and its fine but under class="foo" h2 need to reset black but if I want I would be able to put any other class under foo div and h2 red will be usable.

General h2 > pink

```
<h2>I am pink</h2>

<div class="foo">
<h2>I am black</h2>
</div>

<div class="foo">
<div class="somestyle">
<h2>I am red</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

thanks for your help

Comment: With "reset" you mean to revert to the defaults of the browser? The user preferences? Hm, I'm not sure that's possible for most styles. You have `font-size:medium`, but that's about it.

Comment: I know it doesn't help now, but this is one of those times where the future will be great. Check out HTML5 `scoped` CSS: http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take into account the order of precedence within css (or the cascade), if you declare your `h2` element to be pink globally, than it will be read as pink regardless of where it stands. Unless you specify a different style under a certain class will it be changed. So, in your case, the css will be read like this:

```
h2 {
    color:pink;
}
```

• All `h2` elements will be displayed as pink

```
.foo h2 {
    color: black;
}
```

• Under the `.foo` class all `h2` elements will be displayed as black.

```
.somestyle h2 {
    color:red;
}
```

• Under the `.somestyle` class all `h2` elements will be displayed as red.

You can get around that by being more specific with your selectors, like so:

```
.somestyle .foo h2 {
    color:blue;
}
```

• Here you're selecting any `h2` element, which is a child of `.foo` who is a child of `.somestyle` and giving a different color. Notice the specifics of that selector `.somestyle .foo`, as opposed to a less specific selector like `.foo`.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vkpHK/)

Notice how the order was written. First you have your global `h2` style given, and then you specify different colors under other classes to overwrite that order. So it's all about organization.

Here is a good article on order of precedence: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Note: I don't recommend you use the !important declaration as it disrupts the natural flow of your rules, use proper specific selectors instead.

Answer (score 1):

CSS interits from the parent element, so go up the HTML tree from the target make declarations that match the HTML structure:

```
.foo h2 { color:#000000 }

.foo .somestyle h2 { color:#ff0000 }
```

Comment: I tried that but this is too much work and some need !important also maybe double !important even?

Comment: !important is usually a good indicator that you need to re-factor your HTML/CSS. It's a blunt tool that should be avoided whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `!important` directive

Take a look: [important](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/)